# Creating Windows Cluster with Powershell

Tags: powershell, cluster, failovercluster, windows-cluster, psexec

I have a Windows cluster provisioning script. I am not able to execute the New-Cluster command as Administrator. It says that the user should be a domain user to be able to execute the command.

I m trying to use PSExec to login as a domain user and try if the command is working, but still with no success.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PSTools\PsExec.exe -s -u name -p "pass" -accepteula cmd /c "powershell  -noprofile & { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"C:\scripts\cluster-config.ps1`" " -Verb RunAs; exit }"
```

(I have passed the params correctly while executing)

The cluster-config.ps1

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$clusterName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$srv1,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$srv2,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$clusterIP
)

#Create and configure the WinCluster
New-Cluster -Name $clusterName -Node $srv1,$srv2 -StaticAddress $clusterIP -AdministrativeAccessPoint ActiveDirectoryAndDns
```

How can I create a Windows Cluster as ad Administrator? Unfortunately direct login with domain user credentials is not possible.

Comment: Why direct login is not possible ?

Comment: The whole set up is part of automatio. Unfortunately, wimrn login with domain user is not possible.

Comment: Doing a `New-PSSession` as the appropriate user isn't an option?

Comment: Do NOT use psexec (crit cve's).  Instead try invoke-command.

Answer (score 0):

**No:**

1. New-Cluster doesn't need to be run on the actual cluster node.
2. New-Cluster creates AD objects and DNS records. You will need an AD authentication
3. New-Cluster [cannot be run remotely without Credential Security Service Provider (CredSSP) authentication on the server computer.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/new-cluster?view=win10-ps)

And without knowing more about your situation, I can't really make better recommendations, but consider working with your AD admins to [prestage clusters and nodes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/configure-ad-accounts)